# LibGdx - Serious memory leaks when switching Screens

Tags: java, android, ios, memory-leaks, libgdx

I have an UI with 4 Screens, my app is pretty heavy atm and starts off at about 250MB Ram usage, after I switch back and forth between Screens a few time, it rises fast, up to 800MB Ram before it crashes.

This is how I deal with disposal:

Each Screen `extends` MainScreen, where I have this dispose method:

```
@Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        stage.dispose();
        System.out.println("Disposing Main Screen");
    }
```

When setting a new Screen I do this:

```
dispose();
game.setScreen(new HighScoreScreen(game));
```

Now I load all my assets using the `AssetManager` at launch, which means I don't unload/dipose any resources in the Screens because that will cause the next Screen to show an empty black box instead of the asset that was disposed. But is this a problem? I have a lot of resources, for example 8 different `BitmapFonts` That are initialized each time I load a new Screen that extends MainScreen. However if I try disposing these I get an error the next time I try to initialize them.

The only things left that are diposable are textures/fonts, so is this what is causing my problem? Should I load/unload for each Screen? This seems like it would lead to a bad user experience with a lot of loading.

Comment: What's the approximately resolution of your assets?

Comment: @BigTony.D I use 1080x1800 resolution, UI uses one bg and 3 atlases, as well as a few fonts and some sound.

Comment: Have you tried to make that assets smaller? We've got similar problem with iOS, when we were forced to scale down all assets to max. resolution of 1024 x 1024, because of crashing app on iOS.

Comment: @BigTony.D We kinda see that as a plan B, we know our res is large but atm we are hendeling that in a good way, it is memory leaks that is the problem

Comment: Reuse BitmapFonts instead of initializing each load. Search for similar initializations.

Comment: @TomGrillGames I was thinking maybe re-use all assets? i.e pass the atlas/fonts in the Screen constructors? Any example of what you mean then please post an answer :)

Comment: @MrCharli3 this is what I do. I do have a GameContext class which provides all possible required asset stuff like fonts, sprites, sounds, etc. GameContext is passed in the constructor where required.

Comment: @TomGrillGames I was thinking of creating an Array of Screens that I init. in onCreate(), then just load them using `game.setScreen(game.array.get(nextScreen)); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TomGrill Games said, you should initialize your resources once, and use them from your main class. You might have a resources class, initialized in your main class, and call your resources from there. Your code might look something like:

```
game.setScreen(game.mainScreen);
```

or

```
game.setScreen(game.resources.mainScreen);
```

You would also do that with your sounds, and other resources.

Comment: For sounds and other assets I use the AssetManager :) I keep the assets loaded through the applications lifecycle. But it's good to know that I only should init. my resources like Screens, stages, tables, buttons etc. once!